# Firebase functions: failed to deploy Error 403 failed to read tags for host us.gcr.io

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My project consists of two NodeJS based firebase functions which have been there for months now, I wanted to change some smtp info in one, so modified it but can't deploy anymore.

Things I want to clear before heading further:

1. Yes, I'm properly logged in in the firebase cli.
2. The functions are not new, changes are in only one, that too in strings, errors in both.
3. Yes, I'm the admin of the account.
4. The Firebase tools version is 9.16.5

Steps I took:

1. `firebase deploy --only functions` - Worked fine, functions got deployed.
2. `firebase emulator:start` - read the docs ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function)) to check on localhost, ran it, saw the issue, fixed it and tried deploying again.
3. `firebase deploy --only functions` - resulted to `Unhandled error cleaning up build images` and `Error: Functions did not deploy properly.` (step 1 to 3 took barely 5 minutes).
4. Googled it, found `firebase deploy --only functions --debug` - resulted to the errors:

   ```
   [2021-08-28T20:15:08.518Z] Got sourceToken undefined for region us-central1
   [2021-08-28T20:15:08.525Z] Total Function Deployment time: 7497
   [2021-08-28T20:15:08.525Z] 2 Functions Deployed
   [2021-08-28T20:15:08.530Z] 2 Functions Errored
   [2021-08-28T20:15:08.534Z] Average Function Deployment time: 3751
   i  functions: cleaning up build files...
   [2021-08-28T20:15:08.540Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/x/gcf/us-central1/tags/list [none]
   [2021-08-28T20:15:08.541Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/x/gcf/us-central1/tags/list [none]
   [2021-08-28T20:15:09.692Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/x/gcf/us-central1/tags/list 403
   [2021-08-28T20:15:09.693Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/x/gcf/us-central1/tags/list 
      {"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"Failed to read tags for host 'us.gcr.io', 
      repository '/v2/x/gcf/us-central1/tags/list'"}]}
   [2021-08-28T20:15:09.699Z] Failed docker command with error HTTP Error: 403, 
      Unknown Error {"name":"FirebaseError","children":[],"context":{"body":{"errors":
      [{"code":"DENIED","message":"Failed to read tags for host 'us.gcr.io', repository 
      '/v2/x/gcf/us-central1/tags/list'"}],"error":{"message":"Unknown Error"}},
      "response":{"statusCode":403}},"exit":1,"message":"HTTP Error: 403, Unknown Error","status":403}
   ```

Similar answers here on SO or [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/641) didn't help.

Is this some sort of billing issue because in firebase's function logs, I see this message `Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions`, although, the (previously deployed) function gets executed properly. But, I'm already on blaze plan.

**Edit**: I was expecting this issue related to the `firebase emulators:start` command, so, deleted the repository, re-cloned it and tried to deploy it, but no, the error still persists.

**Edit 2**: It is still not working, I've commented additional log on the [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3714) I created which mentions

```
"error":{"code":9,"message":"Cloud storage operation for gcf-sources-704287304411-us-
central1 failed as the billing account is not available"}
```

This hints of a problem with the billing account which seems fine in the billing section of the Firebase console, and the plan is Blaze.

There are some questions on SO in which it has been mentioned that `billing account is not configured` and not `billing account is not available`. And, they don't help either.

Comment: Are you the project owner or check if you have role of `roles/storage.objectAdmin` or project editor?

Comment: @JMGelilio Yes, I'm the project owner and no other collaborators have been added to the project. It stopped working literally under 5 minutes of working fine.